# Waiting for all Ajax calls to complete inside for loop then redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, filereader

I would like to iterate over a `files` array and send each file to our backend (we use D365).

I have the following piece of code:

```
function SaveDocs() {
    $.each(files, function (index, value) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
            var base64 = reader.result == "data:" ? "" : reader.result.split(',')[1];
            var data = JSON.stringify(...);
            // Create Annotation in D365
            $.ajax({
              url: baseUrl + "CreateAnnotation",
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: data,
              contentType: 'application/json'
           });
        };
      reader.readAsDataURL(value);           
    }); // end of for loop
}
```

The above function is called on a click of a button and I would like to redirect the user when all Ajax calls have been completed.

I have tried using this:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
  // files array is already defined and contains data
  SaveDocs();
  Redirect(); // redirects to page where user can view all uploaded files
})
```

The problem is after redirecting. I can only open some files and other files appear as corrupted.
I suspect it is because the Ajax calls inside `reader` have not yet been completed and this is why some files are working and others are 'corrupted'.

I also tried setting the Ajax call as 'async' using `async: false` but the problem persists.
Setting a `Timeout` on `Redirect` did not help either.

Is it because the `reader.onloadend` function itself is asynchronous?

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to make `reader.onloadend` synchronous? I know it's bad practice but I don't mind blocking the user since all I do is redirecting them to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to "promisify" the Reader thing and then use `Promise.all` until all the files are uploaded.

Here is an example which may required some tweaking as I did not test it.

```
SaveDocs = async (event, files) => {
  const filePromises = files.map((file) => {
    // Return a promise per file
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = async () => {
        try {
          var base64 = reader.result == "data:" ? "" : reader.result.split(',')[1];
          var data = JSON.stringify(...);
          const response = await this.submitFile(data);
          // Resolve the promise with the response value
          resolve(response);
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      };
      reader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  });

  // Wait for all promises to be resolved
  const fileInfos = await Promise.all(filePromises);

  console.log('COMPLETED');

  // Profit
  return fileInfos;
};

async submitFile(data) {
  // Create Annotation in D365
  return $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + "CreateAnnotation",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/json'
  });
}
```